# Control Indentation Hanging in PowerPoint 2010 VSTO

Tags: vba, vsto, powerpoint

I have a paragraph and after executing :

```
paragraph.ParagraphFormat.FirstLineIndent = 18;
paragraph.ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = 18;
```

when I check Paragraph dialog box, I get:

- Indentation Before Text 0.25" - OK, this is what I wanted
- Special **First line** 0.25" - it's not what I want.

Instead of **First line** I want to have Special set to **Hanging**. Is it possible to control it with code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > > Instead of First line I want to have Special set to Hanging. Is it possible to control it with code?

Yes it is possible :)

Just remember the thumb rule

For **FirstLine** use a positive value and

For **Hanging** use a negative value

Change your code to

```
paragraph.ParagraphFormat.FirstLineIndent = -18;
```